# What does the acc means in the Keras model.fit output? the accuracy of the final iteration in a epoch or the average accuracy in a epoch?

Tags: python, keras

I want to know the printed accuracy is the accuracy of the final iteration in a epoch or the average accuracy in a epoch?
code:

```
history=model.fit(data,label,nb_epoch=1,batch_size=32,validation_data=(X_test,Y_test))
```

the printed log:

```
Epoch 1/1
```

128/128 [==============================] - 17s - loss: 2.3152 - acc: 0.0859 - val_loss: 2.3010 - val_acc: 0.1157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/) and [history](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-record-the-training-validation-loss-accuracy-at-each-epoch) documentation;

**acc** represents the average training accuracy at the end of an epoch.

**val_acc** represents the accuracy of validation set at the and of an epoch.

Comment: so  is it different if  using fit once and using train_on_batch four times?

Comment: @xingxinghanzi history object records training metrics for each epoch, and it is returned after the end of each epoch. It represents the accuracy for that epoch. If you use train_on_batch four times it will return loss and accuracy metric for each batch four times.

Comment: if using the same data(datas in a batch are same in fit iteration and train_on_batch),the acc and val_acc is same or different after using fit once and using train_on_batch four times? that means spliting the data into 4 batches to using train_on_batch, is the final result same with using fit?

Comment: Not exactly - in `fit` method your data is by default shuffled so your batches should be different.